# How can I merge all my local commit before rebase my local branch from the main?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-squash

When I work in a team and must push my local branch to the remote main, I rebase firstly my local branch to master with this simple command:

```
git fetch && git rebase origin/main
```

But when I do that, all my local commits are applied and conflicts occur because the code of these previous commits are different to my last local state (saved in my last commit). And solving conflicts of my own commits takes a lot of (useless) time...

I’m afraid to do a mishandle, so I search for some help here. My question:

How can I merge all my local commit into one before a rebase ? And thanks that, when I rebase, there is just one commit to apply

I don't know if its the better approach, feel free to give my advise. :)
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I squash my last N commits together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/how-do-i-squash-my-last-n-commits-together)

Comment: It's not elegant (and not the answer), but on GitHub, I often push to a separate fork, create a pull request against a branch that matches the main, squash and merge and then `git cherry-pick...` from that commit hash.  The reason I do this is because the merging strategy from GitHub's Pull Requests often solves this problem in times when local squashing does not or is too much work, especially for branches that have been diverging for a long time.  It also has the added benefit of a side-by-side merge conflict resolver, for those files that actually do conflict after a squash.

Comment: thanks for yours helps ! @teapot418 if I understand, I "flat" all my commit with the squash command and, then, when I `git fetch && git rebase origin/main`, there will be only one commit to merge ?

Comment: Yes, "squash" is the usual term for merging multiple commits into one. (I mostly use the `git rebase -i` variant described in the accepted answer over there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
#!/bin/sh
## Usage: ./script <branch>
git fetch origin main
git checkout origin/main
git merge --squash $1
# You’ll want to modify the commit message here
git commit
git branch --force $1 HEAD
# Return
git checkout -
```

#### Testing

I compared this with running `git rebase <upstream>` on a feature branch
and I got the same tree ids from the two approaches.

The squash also squashed the range that I expected it to, according to
the default commit message (it is quite verbose).

#### Caveat about the commit message

The default commit message of `git merge --squash` is much less nice
than the one you get from `git rebase --interactive` with `squash`.

#### Misc.: reapplying conflicts

If you are just tired of fixing the same merge conflicts over and over
again when using git-rebase(1) then you might want to look into
git-rerere(1).

Comment: works perfectly ! u made my day :D

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that in the following way:

1. `git rebase -i HEAD~n` (where n the number of commits you have above main)
2. An editor will open where you will have to leave `pick` on the top commit and then replace the `pick` in the following lines with an `s`, which stands for squash.
3. In the next editor, edit the commit messages as you wish
4. You will see a message that ways "Successfully rebased..."
5. Then run `git pull --rebase origin main` to put that commit above the commits on the remote branch

Comment: I think it's both easier and safer to use the SHA-1 of the branch root commit, than `HEAD~n`.